# What is $T_{\mu\nu}T_{\mu\nu}$ for the electromagnetic stress-energy tensor?

Tags: electromagnetism, tensor-calculus

Given the electromagnetic stress-energy tensor components
\begin{align}
T_{\mu\nu}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
u_{00} && s_{0 \nu}
\\
s_{\mu 0} && \sigma_{\mu\nu}
\end{pmatrix}_{\mu\nu}
\end{align}
where $u_{00}$ is the energy density, $s_{0 \nu}$ is the poynting vector, and $\sigma_{\mu\nu}$ is the Maxwell stress energy tensor:

What is 
\begin{align}
\sum_{\mu =0}^{3}\sum_{\nu =0}^{3}
T_{\mu\nu}^2
=
?
\end{align}

Comment: Something coordinate dependent, that's for sure. Also, would this be related to [your other question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/103529)?

Comment: I think they might be related. This problem appears to be very difficult to solve to me.