# What is $\langle G_{\mu\nu}\rangle\langle G_{\mu\nu}\rangle$ for the Dirac gamma matrices?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, dirac-matrices

Given the following 16 matrix multiplications of the Dirac gamma matrices
\begin{align}
G_{\mu\nu}
=
\dfrac{1}{2}
\begin{pmatrix}
I && \gamma_{0} && i\gamma_{123} && i\gamma_{0123}
\\
i\gamma_{23} && i\gamma_{023} && i\gamma_{1} && \gamma_{01}
\\
i\gamma_{31} && i\gamma_{031} && i\gamma_{2} && \gamma_{02}
\\
i\gamma_{12} && i\gamma_{012} && i\gamma_{3} && \gamma_{03}
\end{pmatrix},
\end{align}
where $\gamma_{01} = \gamma_{0}\gamma_{1}$:

What is 
\begin{align}
\sum_{\mu=0}^{3}\sum_{\nu=0}^{3}
\langle G_{\mu\nu} \rangle^2
=
?
\end{align}
The Bra-Ket notation is used in this question:
\begin{align}
\langle G_{\mu\nu} \rangle
=
\langle \Psi | G_{\mu\nu} | \Psi \rangle
,
\end{align}
where $\Psi$ is the Dirac bi-spinor of four complex components.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by $\langle \cdots \rangle$?

Comment: I provided more information.

Comment: @linuxfreebird It is not the first time I see this matrix of physics.SE, but I had never seen it before, Do you mind to explain what is it? and How is it obtained?

Comment: @Dox I am not sure how it is obtained from something else, I just noticed that given all possible gamma matrices, there exists only 16 unique matrix multiplication of the gamma matrices. I was just curious if the gamma matrices satisfied a similar property belonging to the Pauli matrices posted here http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/103618/what-is-langle-sigma-mu-rangle-langle-sigma-mu-rangle-for-the-pauli?lq=1