# What is $\langle \sigma_\mu \rangle$ $\langle \sigma_\mu \rangle$ for the Pauli Matrices?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, quantum-spin

What is 
\begin{align}
\sum_{\mu=0}^{3}
\langle \sigma_{\mu} \rangle^2
=
?
\end{align}
$\sigma_{\mu}$ are the Pauli matrices. The Bra-Ket notation is used in this question:
\begin{align}
\langle \sigma_{\mu} \rangle
=
\langle \Psi \lvert \sigma_{\mu} \lvert \Psi \rangle
,
\end{align}
where $\Psi$ is the Pauli spinor of two complex components.

Comment: Why don't you just *calculate it directly* for ***arbitrary***  |Ψ= |(α,β)〉 and its Hermitean conjugate, so that it is normalized, αbar α+βbar β=1 ??? What stands between you and 1 for the sum of the squares of the expectation values you computed for the 3 Pauli matrices, + 1 for your euclidean metric, as defined, and -1 if you chose to subtract the identity term, instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to a slightly different question—what is the $\langle\sigma_{\mu} \sigma_{\mu}\rangle$—is 4 since the Pauli's independently square to the identity.

EDIT: This is incorrect. The answer should be 2 since the $\mu = 0$ term has a minus sign attached to it, as @JeffDror pointed out in the comments.

Onto your question. Let's start off by asking what is $\langle\sigma_{\mu}\rangle$ in the state $\left|n\right\rangle$ (my notation means that the spin is aligned along the unit vector n).

Well, let's say $\mu = 3$—then if the spin makes an angle $\theta$ with the z-axis the expectation of $\sigma_3$ will be $\cos(\theta)$, just the projection of the spin onto the z direction. Similarly, $\sigma_1$ will have expectation $\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi)$, where $\phi$ is the azimuthal angle, and $\sigma_2$ will have expectation $\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)$ (this can all be proved explicitly using the fact that $\left|n\right\rangle = (\cos(\theta/2),e^{i\phi}\sin(\theta/2))$).

In any event, it is clear that $\langle\sigma_{\mu}\rangle\langle\sigma_{\mu}\rangle = 1$.

EDIT: As @JeffDror pointed out, I neglected the $\mu = 0$ term. This trivially has expectation $\langle\sigma_0\rangle = \langle\sigma_0\rangle\langle\sigma_0\rangle = 1$. However, there is a minus sign built into the Minkowski metric with which the sum over $\mu$ is being performed, so this term cancels the positive one contribution from the $\mu = 1,2,3$ components, and the total sum is indeed zero.

Comment: I think you are missing the $<\sigma_0>$ term which gives a $1$ and including the relative minus sign between the spatial and temporal components the answer should be $0$.

Comment: Haha, I know. I just get lazy in comments.

Comment: Good start to answering the question. Can you prove it for any spinor orientation and spin orientation?

Comment: The above discussion does prove it for any orientation. The angles, $\phi$ and $\theta$ are arbitrary.

Comment: @JeffDror you're completely right thanks for catching my error

Comment: @linuxfreebird Jeff is correct. Any orientation can be described by some value of $\theta$ and $\phi$.

Comment: @GlenTheUdderboat I wasn't aware of those symbols in LaTeX. Thanks for the tip! Will update the answer accordingly.

EDIT: oh, you beat me to it. Thank you!

Comment: This was the first start to solving an even tougher problem located here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/103529/what-is-langle-g-mu-nu-rangle-langle-g-mu-nu-rangle-for-the-dirac-gamma